# Android Realm migration issue: Can an older version of an app get stuck with the data files of a newer version?

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

When an Android app is updated using the package manager API is it possible for it to get into a state where the app has data files from the newer version of the app yet the older version of the app is still installed and running on the phone?

I'm diagnosing an Android app on a handset returned from a customer that was developed using Realm 1.0.0 database. It appears the app failed to update to a newer version of our software for some reason. The newer version of the app had a schema v4. The older version of the app had schema v3. We don't use the Play Store for distributing upgrades. We have our own web servers where the app downloads APK file upgrades of itself which are then installed by invoking the Package Manager with the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

When the app starts it crashes with the following error:

> Realm on disc is newer then the one specified. V4 vs V3.

If I look in Settings > Apps I can see the app installed is the older version using V3 of our schema. Yet the .realm file the app is loading from internal storage has a v4 schema belonging to the newer version of our app.

The app runs on a Moto E2 phone running Lollipop 5.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like some user downgraded your app most likely?

Realm doesn't have support for downgrading Realm files automatically. If you wish to allow downgrades, you need to still bump the schema version to the next level : 4 -> 5, and specify the migration there as the inverse of 3 - > 4.

Given your scenario that sounds impossible, since I assume a user can downgrade to any previous version?

In that case you have two choices:

1) Detect that a downgrade has happened by catching that exception and show a warning to the user that they cannot downgrade.

2) Detect that a downgrade has happened and delete the Realm file.

Comment: Downgrades of the app should not be possible. It runs on a kiosked device which physically blocks access to the USB data port preventing side-loading by ADB. App upgrades are not distributed through the Play Store but through our own cloud infrastructure which is not accessible without an auth token and the downloaded APKs are deleted from the file system once successfully upgraded. A bit of a mystery!